# Usando Visual Studio e C++ como evitar que a tela do debug feche automaticamente?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Usando o código abaixo eu digito os dois números, mas se eu der enter depois de digitar o segundo número a resposta aparece rapidamente e o debug fecha.

```
int main(){

int num1, num2, answer;

cout << "Digite um número:";
cin >> num1;

cout << "Digite um número:";
cin >> num2;

answer = num1 * num2;
cout << "Resultado:" << answer << endl;

cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Eu coloquei

```
cin.get();
```

mas não funcionou.

Estou tentando usar o Ctrl + F5 para  debugar, mas clicar no F5 trava meu cursor e tenho que clicar novamente para destravar, por que?

Answer (score 3):

Voce deve inserir um "break point" no código, assim o depurador vai parar e você pode visualizar as informações do contexto de execução.

Utilize as teclas de atalhos para executar passo-a-passo o código. Se sua IDE estiver configurada para o padrão de atalhos do Visual Studi 6 (Tools->Options->Environment->Keyborad), para projetos C++, use :
F5 - executa até o ponto de parada, se existir;
F9 - insere ponto de parada/remove ponto de parada (break point) na posição onde está o cursos, ou posição mais próxima válida;
F10 - executa passo-a-passo;
F11 - entra na rotina.

Comment: Em qual linha insiro o "breakpoint". Inseri depois do return, testei antes e a janela continua fechando. A IDE está configurada como "default/padrão".

Comment: E se eu compilasse o aplicativo, o breakpoint continuaria funcionando para o usuário?

Comment: Mudei para VS6, ma sos atalhos não funcionam, se aperto F5 meu cursor trava.

Comment: coloque o cursos na linha "answer = num1 * num2;", tecle F9 e depois F5. A execução deve parar ali. O break só funciona em depuração. A versão que você vai distribuir deve ser compilado como release.

Answer (score 1):

Após fazer uma pesquisa, verifiquei que posso evitar que a tela de debug feche usando:

```
 system("PAUSE");
```

Answer (score 0):

usa-se

```
system("pause");
```

Mas para usar essa ferramenta tens que adicionar uma biblioteca a mais a

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```